# Contour integral around the unit circle: $∮_{|z|}z^2 e^{-1/z}dz $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Compute the following contour integral around the unit circle
$$∮_{|z|}z^2 e^{-1/z}dz
$$

---

What I have tried
$$
z(t)=cos(t)+isin(t)=e^{it}
$$
then by taking derivative of $z(t)$
we arrive at
$$\dot{z(t)}=ie^{it}$$
After substituting these values into the given problem, integration becomes really difficult to solve
$$∮_0^{2\pi}e^{2it} e^{-1/{e^{it}}}ie^{it}dt
$$
Could you assist me with this problem?

Comment: Hint: Try expanding $e^{-1/z}$ in a Laurent series.

Comment: Try using the Taylor series of the exponential and note that the only term that doesn't integrate to zero is the one with power $z^{-3}$

Comment: @podiki  thank you for your comments, I did as you said then we obtain Laurent series whose principal part is an infinite series. But how should I integrate it, it is infinite...

Comment: Do you know what a residue is? Or how to evaluate integrals of the form $\oint_C z^n dz$ for closed curves around the origin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ z^2e^{-\frac{1}{z}} = z^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{z^nn!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}z^{2-n}$$
so the residue at 0 is $ \frac{(-1)^3}{3!} = -\frac{1}{6}$,
$$ \oint_{|z|=1}z^2e^{-\frac{1}{z}}\ dz = 2\pi i \times(-\frac{1}{6}) = -\frac{\pi i}{3}$$

Comment: All thank you for your comments. I was on my learning these topics. I found out the Ch15 and 16 in E.Kreyszig's book have provided the guide how to solve these questions!

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{aligned}\displaystyle \text{Res}_{z=0} f(z) &= -\text{Res}_{z=\infty} \,f(z)=  \text{Res}_{z=0}\,\frac{1}{z^2} f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) \\
\text{Res}_{z=0}\,  {z^2}\exp(1/z) &=  - \text{Res}_{z=\infty}\,  z^2 \exp(1/z)= \text{Res}_{z=0}\, \frac{1}{z^4} e^{-z}\\
&= \text{Res}_{z=0}\, \frac{1}{z^4} \left(1 - z + \frac{z^2}{2!} - \frac{z^3}{3!} + \cdots  \right)\\&= - \frac{1}{3!} \\
\oint z^2 \exp(1/z) \, dz &= -\frac{2\pi i}{6} = -\frac{\pi i}{3}
\end{aligned}$$